# Xamrin forms System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: xamarin

Hi I am getting this exception when using Azure mobile services offline store when debugging in Android. It works fine when using windows though.

Here is the code, just based on the tod0list example

```
    static StaffManager defaultInstance = new StaffManager();
    MobileServiceClient client;

    IMobileServiceSyncTable<Staff> staffTable;

    private StaffManager()
    {
        client = new MobileServiceClient(Constants.ApplicationURL);

            var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("localstore1.db");
            store.DefineTable<Staff>();

            this.client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);

            this.staffTable = client.GetSyncTable<Staff>();

    }
```

This is the exception:

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'OrchardApp.StaffManager' threw an exception.

09-26 11:05:48.991 D/Mono    ( 1684): DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
09-26 11:05:48.991 D/Mono    ( 1684): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
09-26 11:05:48.991 D/Mono    ( 1684): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so' ('/system/lib/liblog.so').
09-26 11:05:48.991 D/Mono    ( 1684): Searching for '__android_log_print'.
09-26 11:05:48.991 D/Mono    ( 1684): Probing '__android_log_print'.
09-26 11:05:48.991 D/Mono    ( 1684): Found as '__android_log_print'.
09-26 11:05:48.991 I/MonoDroid( 1684): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
09-26 11:05:48.991 I/MonoDroid( 1684): System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'OrchardApp.StaffManager' threw an exception. ---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore.SQLiteException: Error executing SQLite command: 'unable to open database file'.
09-26 11:05:48.991 I/MonoDroid( 1684):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore.SQLitePCLRawHelpers.VerifySQLiteResponse (Int32 result, Int32 expectedResult, SQLitePCL.sqlite3 db) [0x00024] in :0 
09-26 11:05:48.991 I/MonoDroid( 1684):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore.SQLitePCLRawHelpers.GetSqliteConnection (System.String filename) [0x0000d] in :0 
09-26 11:05:48.991 I/MonoDroid( 1684):   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore.MobileServiceSQLiteStore..ctor (System.String fileName) [0x00039] in :0 
09-26 11:05:48.991 I/MonoDroid( 1684):   at OrchardApp.StaffManager..ctor () [0x0001e] in C:\OPAC\OrchardApp\OrchardApp\OrchardApp\Services\StaffManager.cs:27 
09-26 11:05:48.991 I/MonoDroid( 1684):   at OrchardApp.StaffManager..cctor () [0x00000] in C:\OPAC\OrchardApp\OrchardApp\OrchardApp\Services\StaffManager.cs:16 
09-26 11:05:48.991 I/MonoDroid( 1684):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
09-26 11:05:48.991 I/MonoDroid( 1684):   at OrchardApp.TodoList..ctor () [0x0000f] in C:\OPAC\OrchardApp\OrchardApp\OrchardApp\Views\TodoList.xaml.cs:18 
09-26 11:05:48.991 I/MonoDroid( 1684):   at OrchardApp.HomePage+<<-ctor>b__0_1>d.MoveNext () [0x0000f] in C:\OPAC\OrchardApp\OrchardApp\OrchardApp\Views\HomePage.xaml.cs:26 
09-26 11:05:48.991 I/MonoDroid( 1684): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
09-26 11:05:48.991 I/MonoDroid( 1684):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
09-26 11:05:48.995 I/MonoDroid( 1684):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.m__0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1018 
09-26 11:05:48.995 I/MonoDroid( 1684):   at Android.App.SyncContext+c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:18 
09-26 11:05:48.995 I/MonoDroid( 1684):   at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36 
09-26 11:05:48.995 I/MonoDroid( 1684):   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:81 
09-26 11:05:48.995 I/MonoDroid( 1684):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:578fa2b5-486e-424f-9b2b-bb0dcaf1a772 (intptr,intptr)
09-26 11:05:49.003 D/Mono    ( 1684): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
09-26 11:05:49.003 D/Mono    ( 1684): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
09-26 11:05:49.003 D/Mono    ( 1684): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
09-26 11:05:49.003 D/Mono    ( 1684): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
An unhandled exception occured.

Comment: To get an answer you would have to specify the Exception (message and where it occurs). Here's some tips on debugging Xamarin:
http://xamariniac.hlinteractive.se/index.php/2016/09/22/debugging-xamarin-and-cross-platform-exceptions/

Comment: Hi I have added the exception details

Comment: Some suggest downgrading Azure Mobile Services (to 2.1.1 in their case).
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/78936/microsoft-azure-mobile-client-sqlitestore-upgraded-to-3-0-get-error-unable-to-open-database-file

Answer (score 1):

See comment from Thomas Hagstrom.
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/78936/microsoft-azure-mobile-client-sqlitestore-upgraded-to-3-0-get-error-unable-to-open-database-file

Downgrading to version 2.1.1 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem with version 3.0.0 in PCL project I have resolved with [this](https://emanuelefilardo.wordpress.com/2016/09/27/xamarin-forms-pcl-microsoft-azure-mobile-client-sqlitestore-android-typeinitializationexception/) workaround

PCL Project App.cs

```
        public static string Path = "MyLocalStore.db";
```

Android Project MainActivity.cs nel metodo OnCreate

```
        //Call this in each platform before intializing your Mobile Client
        SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init();

        App.Path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), App.Path);

        if (!File.Exists(App.Path))
        {
            File.Create(App.Path).Dispose();
        }
```

Finally

```
        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(App.Path);
```